# What is the way to store array of object_id and its coordinates in database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have an application on rails 3 with PostgreSQL database.

The problem is: I want to store coordinates with an object_id to access it like:

```
Post1 -> Coordinates [100,200] -> Attachment1
Post1 -> Coordinates [400,400] -> Attachment2
Post1 -> Coordinates [200,500] -> Attachment3

Post2 -> Coordinates [150,310] -> Attachment1

Post3 -> Coordinates [50,710] -> Attachment1
Post1 -> Coordinates [430,430] -> Attachment2
```

I'd want to store all the attachments,  with coordinates in one place (i.e. Coordinating model) not to make the things messy. Is it possible?

I've never met any way of solving this or similar.

Comment: Are those coordinates on a sphere?

Comment: from your example it looks that single attachment can be associated with multiple coordinates: Attachment1: [100,200], [150,310], [50,710]. What's the relation between Coordinates and Attachments: one-to-many or many-to-many? Could you please clarify this "store all the attachments, with coordinates in one place"? Do you want to store everything in single table?

Comment: @Tass: Not for sphere, but for (x,y) grid

Comment: @OndrejIvanic: many-to-many. Only coordinates and relation.
In one Post Att1 has one placement, in other Post - another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a simple m:n relationship with a two-part key. Model it relationally with a joint table. To give you the idea, assuming there can only be one `(post, attachment)` pair per c-ordinate location, the SQL phrasing would be:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    post_id serial primary key,
    blah_other_data text
);

CREATE TABLE attachment (
    attachment_id serial primary key,
    blah_other_data text
);

CREATE TABLE post_attachment (
    post_id integer not null REFERENCES post(post_id),
    attachment_id integer not null REFERENCES attachment(attachment_id), 
    coordinate_x integer not null,
    coordinate_y integer not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (coordinate_x, coordinate_y)
);
```

I'm sure you can translate that back into Rails models and queries.

If there can be multiple `(post,attachment)` pairs per co-ordinate location then you must adjust the `PRIMARY KEY` of `post_attachments` to permit that by adding the co-ordinate columns to the key.

Demo data setup:

```
INSERT INTO post (blah_other_data)
VALUES ('Post1'),('Post2'),('Post3');

INSERT INTO attachment(blah_other_data)
VALUES ('Attachment1'),('Attachment2'),('Attachment3');

INSERT INTO post_attachment (post_id, attachment_id, coordinate_x, coordinate_y)
SELECT post_id, attachment_id, x, y
FROM (VALUES
    ('Post1', 100,200, 'Attachment1'),
    ('Post1', 400,400, 'Attachment2'),
    ('Post1', 200,500, 'Attachment3'),
    ('Post2', 150,310, 'Attachment1'),
    ('Post3', 50,710,  'Attachment1'),
    ('Post1', 430,430, 'Attachment2')
) rows(post_data,x,y,attachment_data)
INNER JOIN post ON (post.blah_other_data = rows.post_data)
INNER JOIN attachment ON (attachment.blah_other_data = rows.attachment_data);
```

Access the data with joins:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.blah_other_data AS post_data, 
       a.attachment_id, a.blah_other_data AS attachment_data, 
       c.coordinate_x, c.coordinate_y 
FROM post_attachment c 
INNER JOIN post p ON (c.post_id = p.post_id) 
INNER JOIN attachment a ON (c.attachment_id = a.attachment_id);
 post_id | post_data | attachment_id | attachment_data | coordinate_x | coordinate_y 
---------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------
       3 | Post3     |             1 | Attachment1     |           50 |          710
       2 | Post2     |             1 | Attachment1     |          150 |          310
       1 | Post1     |             1 | Attachment1     |          100 |          200
       1 | Post1     |             2 | Attachment2     |          400 |          400
       1 | Post1     |             2 | Attachment2     |          430 |          430
       1 | Post1     |             3 | Attachment3     |          200 |          500
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Is [this](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org) the proper way to implement complex primary keys?

Comment: @sadfuzzy I'm not into Rails and ActiveRecord particularly, so I can't really help with that part. I'm stunned that it doesn't support composite keys out of the box. If you need to you can change the data model to add a synthetic primary key, and make the co-ordinates `UNIQUE (coordinate_x, coordinate_y)` instead.

Comment: @sadfuzzy A quick search suggests it's a bad idea for Rails because the ActiveRecord folks disagree with the idea of composite keys and won't integrate support for them. They're believers in synthetic keys. So adjust the data model to add a `coordinate_id serial primary key` column and make `(coordinate_x, coordinate_y)` a `UNIQUE` constraint (if it's supposed to be unique, of course) instead of the primary key.